# Is reading server configuration files the right context to use fs.readFileSync?

Tags: node.js

I have to do two things:

1. Read the configure file and calculate some values
2. check if the file is modified and if so, recalculate the values. this way the server does not have to be restarted if the configuration changes

I wonder if this is a good use case to use readFileSync

the problem is mainly on the watch because if the configuration changes, the services that use it no longer have the right parameters so it seems reasonable to me to block execution, however perhaps the parameters of only some services change, if the others work it is not right to block them.

my idea is somthing like that:

```
class Config {
  static data;
  constructor(){
    watchFile()
    update()
  }
  update() {
    this.data = readFileSync()
  }
  onChange(callback) { 
   update()
   this.onChange = callback
  }
}

//

new Config()

// another file
import Config
const { a, b, c } = Config.data
const db = new DB(a, b)
c.onChange(v => db.update(v.a, v.b))
```